# Copy exact state of local git repo to another local repo

Tags: git

Is there a way to copy the exact state of a local git repo (uncommitted changes and all) to another local repo?

The destination repo should be switched to the exact state of the source repo, including the branch, commit and any uncommitted changes since the last commit - edits, new files, deletions...

Short of copying the entire directory every time I need this functionality, I can't think how to do it.

Obviously checking the destination repo out to the same commit will be easy, however it's the uncommitted changes I'm not sure about.

Edit (why I want this!)
I am building a local build system (for Unity games). Normally whilst a build is underway inside of Unity you can't use the program for anything else, so I have a system where another instance of Unity makes the build on a carbon copy of the project files. Each time I trigger a build I delete the old copy and make a new copy, however my thinking is that if the copy is on the same commit and say only two uncommitted files different it would be much quicker just to patch the state. I make builds of uncommitted work whilst testing so commiting changes isn't really an option!

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to do this? If this is for teaching a class or something, have you considered writing a script that would create/edit files and make commits etc.?

Comment: Yes, you copy the directory; it contains the entire repository. But you shouldn't have to do that very often. Why do you need to do this? There's probably a better way. Perhaps using [`git-stash`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning)?

Comment: Sorry yes I didn't say what my goal was. See updated post!

Answer (score 3):

> Short of copying the entire directory every time I need this functionality, I can't think how to do it.

What’s wrong with copying the entire directory? If you really prefer not to (e.g. because it is huge), use any folder synchronization utility, such as `rsync`. I use both those approaches very often.

Comment: Well my thinking was that if the destination repo was say already on the same commit, and all that needs doing to syncronise their states is copy over 4 new uncommitted files then I should be able to just copy the uncommitted files over vs copying a potentially several hundred mb folder. That being said, it still wouldn't take too long to copy the folder locally so I may be creating complexity where there is no need!

Comment: I can understand that, and that is why I said you could use `rsync` or similar. As I say, I do this all the time, for the very same reason. The `.git` contents are ordinary files so `rsync` or any file sync utility "just works" as it normally would, and thus you do indeed end up with the copy in _exactly_ the same "git" state. Simply make sure that "theirs" always "wins" the sync. (In fact I wrote my own folder sync utility to do this, but you'd need to be on Mac to use it, and it's not for the faint of heart.)

Comment: Yes rsync sounds like it will do the trick, thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, one word of advice: do a dry run first (or practice on a copy). This is powerful stuff, you can hose the repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an archiver (`tar` or whatever) to collect the entire repository-and-work-tree state and copying that to some other file-tree area:

```
cd /path/to
tar cf - repo | (cd /different/path; tar xf -)
```

for instance copies the entire file-tree from `/path/to/repo` to `/different/path/repo`.  This copies both the repository itself—all the files in `.git`—and the work-tree (all the files that *aren't* in `.git`).

There are a few caveats here.  The most important is that the `.git` underneath the top level of the work-tree must really be a directory containing the repository, not just a file like those created by `git worktree add`.

Using in-Git methods, such as `git clone`, won't work: they only copy the *repository*.  The work-tree is *not part of the repository:*

> Short of copying the entire directory every time I need this functionality, I can't think how to do it.

That's because Git literally *won't* do it.  The work-tree—*your* work-tree—is *yours*, not Git's, and it's not part of the Git repository.  It's just there *next to* the repository, which is the stuff in the `.git` subdirectory.

If you have Git 2.5 or later—preferably 2.15 or later, because there was a pretty nasty bug in it until then<sup>1</sup>—whatever you are thinking of doing like this is probably better handled through `git worktree add`.  That creates a *separate* work-tree, which again is yours and not Git's, in which Git does a `git checkout` of some commit or branch of your choice at the time you run `git worktree add`.  That second work-tree *doesn't* have its own repository: it uses the original work-tree's repository, by creating a file named `.git` instead of a directory named `.git`.

(The actual repository acquires, at the point of `git worktree add`, a lot of state files to track the existence of this added work-tree.  The added work-tree requires adding a new index, new `HEAD`, and so on, all of which are dedicated to the new work-tree and separate from the index and `HEAD` and so on for the primary work-tree, which is still sitting next to the main repository.  Note that if you later copy the actual repository using the above `tar` trick, it will still think it has these added work-trees.  If they do still exist, that's fine; if not, `git worktree prune` will make the copied repository update its notion of how the outside world looks.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The bug is that `git gc` failed to look in the added `HEAD` and index and such files.  This means that if you:

- use a detached HEAD in the added work-tree, and make new commits, they get deleted (!), and
- even if you don't use a detached HEAD, if you `git add` updated files but don't commit, any new repository-level blob objects can be deleted (!)

which results in a mess.

The standard default 14 day grace period means that if you get all your work done within 14 days and then discard the added work-tree, this bug never hits you, so if you have a Git version below 2.15, you can use `git worktree add` safely as long as you do everything *in* the added work-tree within two weeks.

(The bug actually bit me, though.  Fortunately the added work-tree was merely an experiment that I had abandoned but had not gotten around to removing, and I was able to clean things up.)

Comment: gnu's `tar` has a `C` option, in your source directory you can `tar c . |  tar Cx /path/to/dest`, and it's got a `T` option, so you can `find -name .git -prune -o  -print | tar Tc - | tar Cx /path/to/dest` to do a quickie external archive of your work tree(s).

Comment: @jthill Yes, I just wanted this to work for cases of archivers that don't have a chdir option (not sure which ones those might be).